# Oracle BI Publisher, select different columns by parameter

Tags: oracle, parameters, publisher

I'm just starting with Oracle BI Publisher and I really don't know how to get along with my task.

My project is to ask the user for a parameter (that's ok), and if the user chooses 01, I should display ONLY 'january' with some data. If the user chooses 03, I should display 3 columns, 'january' 'february' 'march' with some data in each.

I have all of the columns till december, I just don't know how to select different number of columns based on the given parameter.

EDITED, ADDED CODE!

```
declare
p SYS_REFCURSOR;

begin

if (:month)=02 then
open p for select 'bazisev' as evtipus, month-1 as month, january, february
    from db.tablename where month=(:month)-1 and sorszam between 4 and 15
  union all
  select 'targyev' as evtipus, month, january, february 
    from db.tablename where month=(:month) and sorszam between 4 and 15
  union all
  select 'targyev/bazisev' as evtipus, month, january, february
    from db.tablename where month=(:month) and sorszam between 32 and 39 
  order by sorszam;

elsif (:month)=01 then

open p for select 'bazisev' as evtipus, month-1 as month, january
    from db.tablename where month=(:month)-1 and sorszam between 4 and 15
  union all
  select 'targyev' as evtipus, month, january
    from db.tablename where month=(:month) and sorszam between 4 and 15
  union all
  select 'targyev/bazisev' as evtipus, month, january
    from db.tablename where month=(:month) and sorszam between 32 and 39 
  order by sorszam;

end if;

end
```

So right now i'm doing it like this with 2 months, but it says: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I'm pretty sure i have all the parenthesis i needed. Any suggesting?

Comment: You cannot have dynamic columns in pure SQL. You need to do it programmatically (ab)using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. In an `IF-ELSE` construct, prepare the dynamic sql and then execute it based on the input values.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the data model - SQL query?

I mean something like:
case when :month=01 then select january from table
         when :month=03 then select january, february, march from table
Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Is it OK to have all columns, however, data to be populated only for the required columns? Or, do you want to display only required columns?

Comment: Another way in PL/SQL would be to open cursor depending on input values.

Comment: @LalitKumarB well, it would be the best if i could the both of them, that way i could do 1 layout for each solution and the user could choose the one which fits him better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the user chooses 01, I should display ONLY 'january' with some data. If the user chooses 03, I should display 3 columns, 'january' 'february' 'march' with some data in each.

You cannot have dynamic columns in pure SQL. You need to do it programmatically (ab)using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**. In an `IF-ELSE` construct, prepare the **dynamic SQL** and then execute it based on the **input values**.

**Pseudo code:** You need to take care of the output type.

```
DECLARE
   v_str VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   IF :id = 1
      THEN v_str := 'SELECT january FROM table_name';
   ELSIF :id = 2
      THEN v_str := 'SELECT january, february FROM table_name';
   ELSIF...
   .
   .
   .
   ELSIF :id = 12
      THEN v_str := 'SELECT january, february...,december FROM table_name';
   END IF;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str...
END;
```

Another way is to use **REFCURSOR**. For example,

```
DECLARE

r SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
   IF :id = 1
      THEN open r for SELECT january FROM table_name;
   ELSIF :id = 2
      THEN open r for SELECT january, february FROM table_name;
   ELSIF...
   .
   .
   .
   ELSIF :id = 12
      THEN open r for SELECT january, february...,december FROM table_name';
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I edited my question, added my current code for 2 months, but i get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error. I'm pretty sure i didn't miss any parenthesis. Any suggestion?

Comment: And what is the exact error stack? it will have the line number too. Open SQL*Plus, and then copy paste the entire session in your question.

Comment: I found the error. It was simple, I can't use dynamic sql in Data Set - Standard SQL. If I use Non-Standard SQL it displays no errors, but i don't get any columns back. How should I deal with it? Do you have any suggestion? @LalitKumarB

Comment: Is there any way to execute PL/SQL objects? Or is the tool capable to execute only pure SQL?